# stop wordpress search showing a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, search

I have one custom post type I use for some text blocks on a page built using uncode theme. I need these blocks to be public so they display on the page but I want to stop them appearing in search results.

The search.php isn't like a normal wordpress search file, it is the uncode-theme file and doesn't have normal queries in I don't think so I'm thinking I need a function maybe?

Can anyone please advise how to achieve this?

The CPT is 'staticcontent'

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer here depends on whether you're creating the CPT via your own code, or if another plugin is creating the CPT. See this link for a great explanation of both approaches:

http://www.webtipblog.com/exclude-custom-post-type-search-wordpress/

The basic gist is this:

If you're creating your own CPT, you can add an argument to the register_post_type() call of `'exclude_from_search' => true`

If another plugin / theme is creating the CPT, you need to set this exclude_from_search variable later on, as part of a filter to the CPT, as such:

```
// functions.php

add_action( 'init', 'update_my_custom_type', 99 );

function update_my_custom_type() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    if ( post_type_exists( 'staticcontent' ) ) {

        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['staticcontent']->exclude_from_search = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: My word, so simple thank you!! 

I had registered the CPT myself so just added 'exclude_from_search' => true

Comment: So I just noticed that adding that exclude_from_search line actually stops the content block being displayed on the page were it should be. It disappears. I want the CPT to appear on the page but not in a search. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm.. that's strange, it certainly shouldn't do that. Did you happen to forget the comma at the end of the line of 'exclude_from_search' => true, in your arguments array? If you entirely remove that line from the CPT arguments, does the content come back?

Comment: Hi Greg, no I hadn't omitted the comma, just double checked. The content does come back when I remove the exclude line.

Comment: That's very odd.. I wonder if there's anything strange happening in the page template that's displaying this CPT content. Is it anything special beyond just calling the_content() ?

Comment: Warning! This accepted answer has side effect: it is also makes unvailable pagination at taxonomies that contains post type that was excluded from search. Here some more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269713/custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-pagination-404-error

Answer (score 17):

I don think accepted answer is correct. `exclude_from_search` prevents all `$query = new WP_Query` from returning results.

The core says:

> ...retrieves any type **except** revisions and types with
>   'exclude_from_search' set to TRUE)

This is a common problem and mixup with the *front end search results page* v.s. search posts in the database.

Presenting content using custom queries on front end, needs `exclude_from_search = false` or use another approach and get the content by id directly.

**You need to filter the search front end mechanism instead**. This is a *true* Exclude Post Types From Search, without manually re-build "known" types:

```
function entex_fn_remove_post_type_from_search_results($query){

    /* check is front end main loop content */
    if(is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) return;

    /* check is search result query */
    if($query->is_search()){

        $post_type_to_remove = 'staticcontent';
        /* get all searchable post types */
        $searchable_post_types = get_post_types(array('exclude_from_search' => false));

        /* make sure you got the proper results, and that your post type is in the results */
        if(is_array($searchable_post_types) && in_array($post_type_to_remove, $searchable_post_types)){
            /* remove the post type from the array */
            unset( $searchable_post_types[ $post_type_to_remove ] );
            /* set the query to the remaining searchable post types */
            $query->set('post_type', $searchable_post_types);
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'entex_fn_remove_post_type_from_search_results');
```

And remark `$post_type_to_remove = 'staticcontent';` can be changed to fit any other post type.

**Please make a comment** if Im missing something here, I cant find another way to prevent post type scenarios like this, *showing content by query* but *hide from search/ direct access* to front end users.

Comment: I share your opinion.

Comment: According to this codex page exclude_from_search is for frontend search results. But it has some note.https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

exclude_from_search
    (boolean) (importance) Whether to exclude posts with this post type from front end search results.

Comment: I feel like this should be stated explicitly for future googlers (like myself): this technique is probably what you want instead of the accepted answer. Using `'exclude_from_search' => true` in the CPT config (as recommended by the accepted answer) **will also remove the posts from taxonomy archives**, which is probably not what you want. I just experienced this myself (WP 5.3.2), and you can see OP experienced it too in the comments of the accepted answer. Use the approach in this answer if you just want to affect the search results page.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer but it also removed the posts from the archive pages. So, I think the accepted answer is not correct. I wonder why it has so many upvotes. This answer worked for me. Just copy the code in the functions.php and and replace the word 'staticcontent' with your desired post type.

Comment: This is best and working solution, as accepted answer has side effect: it is also makes unvailable pagination at taxonomies that contains post type that was excluded from search. Here some more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269713/custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-pagination-404-error

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the answer by **Jonas Lundman** is correct and should be the accepted answer.

The `exclude_from_search` parameter does work incorrectly - it excludes the post type from other queries as well.

There is a ticket on WP issue tracking system, but they have closed it as wontfix because they cannot fix this without breaking the backwards compatibility. See [this ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17592) and [this one](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29418) for more details.

I've added additional checks to the solution proposed by **Jonas Lundman**, because:

- in real setups there can be other plugins trying to modify the search query, so simply replacing the `post_type` may cause unexpected results.
- I think it's more flexible to use an array of post types to exclude.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'remove_my_cpt_from_search_results');

function remove_my_cpt_from_search_results($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || !$query->is_search()) {
        return $query;
    }

    // can exclude multiple post types, for ex. array('staticcontent', 'cpt2', 'cpt3')
    $post_types_to_exclude = array('staticcontent');

    if ($query->get('post_type')) {
        $query_post_types = $query->get('post_type');

        if (is_string($query_post_types)) {
            $query_post_types = explode(',', $query_post_types);
        }
    } else {
        $query_post_types = get_post_types(array('exclude_from_search' => false));
    }

    if (sizeof(array_intersect($query_post_types, $post_types_to_exclude))) {
        $query->set('post_type', array_diff($query_post_types, $post_types_to_exclude));
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.